# How to convert ByteArray[] to int16 in Python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a python project I'm strangled in converting a ByteArray having audio data to int16 in python.

Can someone give a heads-up?

I have used libraries such as jep (python).

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#) library. It's a very good library for working with all things audio and is cross platform.

The links [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.paInt16) on the pyadio documentation and [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/52625/pyaudio.paInt16) from an example on programcreek should get you started with your problem.

Comment: That wasn't stated in your question so i didn't know if you were aware :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to go forward to deal with int16 dtype for something custom, I guess you'll need to use something like [numpy.array](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.creation.html) like this (not checked):

```
import numpy as np
# read file or stream in binary mode into a bin_array list
...
# convert binary input values to numpy array with container type int16
np.array([v for v in bin_array], dtype=np.int16)
```